# Using macro-paradise and cross-compiling with 2.12/2.13

Tags: sbt

Since Scala 2.13, [macro-paradise](https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise) has been inlined in the compiler and is available via a compiler flag:

```scala
Compile / scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-annotations"
```

For reference, in previous versions of Scala, macro-paradise was available via a compiler plugin:

```scala
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

What is the canonical way of conditionally add the first setting or the second, according to the value of the Scala version, in a build targetting both Scala 2.12 and 2.13?

I would like to write the following but it doesn’t work:

```scala
CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
  case Some((2, n)) if n >= 13 => Compile / scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-annotations"
  case _ => addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)
}
```

It fails with the following error:

```
error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
      CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
                                               ^
```

---

In the meantime, I can use the following workaround but I wish a simpler solution was supported:

```scala
Compile / scalacOptions ++= {
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, n)) if n >= 13 => "-Ymacro-annotations" :: Nil
    case _ => Nil
  }
}

libraryDependencies ++= {
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, n)) if n >= 13 => Nil
    case _ => compilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full) :: Nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to write

```
CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
  case Some((2, n)) if n >= 13 => Compile / scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-annotations"
  case _ => addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)
}
```

one option is defining a [SBT custom command](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Commands.html) like so

```
def compileWithMacroParadise: Command = Command.command("compileWithMacroParadise") { state =>
  import Project._
  val extractedState = extract(state)
  val stateWithMacroParadise = CrossVersion.partialVersion(extractedState.get(scalaVersion)) match {
    case Some((2, n)) if n >= 13 => extractedState.appendWithSession(Seq(Compile / scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-annotations"), state)
    case _ => extractedState.appendWithSession(addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full), state)
  }
  val (stateAfterCompileWithMacroParadise, _) = extract(stateWithMacroParadise).runTask(Compile / compile, stateWithMacroParadise)
  stateAfterCompileWithMacroParadise
}

commands ++= Seq(compileWithMacroParadise),
addCommandAlias("compile", "compileWithMacroParadise")
```

`sbt compile` should now make appropriate modifications to build state (`stateWithMacroParadise`) before running the `compile` task.

Answer (score 2):

Fully working example, add this code in a `Compiler.scala` file in your `project` directory:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object Compiler extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] =
    Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= (CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
        case Some((2, x)) if x < 13 =>
          Seq(
            compilerPlugin(("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)),
            "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-collection-compat" % "2.1.6"
          )
        case _ => Nil
      }),
      Compile / scalacOptions ++= (CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
        case Some((2, x)) if x >= 13 =>
          Seq("-Ymacro-annotations")
        case _ => Nil
      })
    )

}
```

Note that you have to use `projectSettings`, `buildSettings` will not work

The `"scala-collection-compat"` dependency is another one you typically want when cross compiling 2.12 and 2.13. It let's you do

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
```

Instead of using the deprecated `scala.collection.JavaConverters`

Comment: This should be the accepted solution! Works like a charm :)